# How to use chrome.storage.sync.get to keep displaying an uploaded image as a background for a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

HTML:

```
<input id="background-image" type=file></input>^
```

JS:

```
    document.getElementById('background-image').addEventListener('change', 
    readURL, true);
    function readURL(){
       var file = document.getElementById("background-image").files[0];
       var reader = new FileReader();
       var readFile = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       reader.onloadend = function(){
           chrome.storage.sync.get(["user-background-image"],function(){
            document.getElementById("main-background- 
 image").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";
           });
       document.getElementById("main-background-image").style.backgroundImage = 
    "url(" + reader.result + ")";        
        }
       if(file){
          //reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        }else{
        }
        chrome.storage.local.set({"user-background-image":reader.result}, 
    function(){
            console.log("Set");
        });
    }
```

So what should happen is that the user uploads a picture and the extension would set the picture as its background, but I have to keep re-uploading the picture, is there a way to have the user's picture be the extension's background image without it being reset every time a new tab is opened or the current tab is closed ?

Comment: Check out the [HTML5 FileSystem API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Comment: The callback of sync.get has a parameter which contains your data.